# Firebase Messaging weird behavior for some Android version

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm currently experiencing some weird behavior of Firebase Messaging when used in my Android app. Notifications are not triggered if emulator came from a restart. I figured out that I needed to manually turn wifi or mobile data on then off (or vice versa). Then after that all queued notifications will be displayed consecutively.

Is there some kind of setting I'm missing for FCM in my Android app or in the Messaging API I'm using in the back end?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

1. Tested on Android KitKat, Lollipop, Marshmallow, Nougat, Oreo, and Pie
2. I was able to apply a work around which is to programmatically disable then enable wifi or mobile data. Below is my code.

   ```
   boolean wifi = false;
   ```

   `ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);`

   ```
   if(conMan != null) {

       Log.e(TAG, "NETWORK INFO IS NULL: " + (conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null));
       NetworkInfo netInfo = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();

       if(netInfo != null) {

           wifi = netInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;

       }

   }

   final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

   if(wifi) {

       wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);

   } else {

       try {
           setMobileDataEnabled(SplashScreen.this, false);
       } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   final boolean finalWifi = wifi;

   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {

           if(finalWifi) {

               wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

           } else {

               try {
                   setMobileDataEnabled(SplashScreen.this, true);
               } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

           }}}, 200);
   ```
3. Because of this workaround all FCM notifications in the emulators connected via Wifi are now working. However programmatically turning mobile data on then off is supported only until KitKat (unless you have a rooted phone) which is why my issue still occurs for all Android versions connected via mobile data except for Android Lollipop.

Comment: Is this specific for emulators or have you tried if it works for an actual device?

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't need to turn on/off the mobile data (this itself is an extra permission IIRC). FCM's behavior is to send the messages as soon as feasible -- in your use case, it should arrive without having to restart the connection.